# Umbraco Razor Macro Parameter access with space

Tags: razor, parameters, umbraco

```
I am new to Umbraco. I am currently using Umbraco 7.0. I have created a Razor 
macro with a parameter that will access property from home template page. In My Macro  
due to space only first word of string displays and  rest of the string is not   
displayed. property    
name is sliderHeading with value : My First Slide. Macro inserted in the template is  
as follows :-

@Umbraco.RenderMacro("HomePageSlider", new {mediaId="1084",    
sliderHeading=@Umbraco.Field("sliderHeading")})  
// where sliderHeading is macro parameter.

Macro definition :-
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

@if (Parameter.mediaId != null)
{
 var mediaFolder =  Library.MediaById(Parameter.mediaId);

 if (mediaFolder.Children.Any())
{

     foreach (var mediaItem in mediaFolder.Children)
        {
            <div class="cycle-slide" style="background- 
image:url(@mediaItem.umbracoFile)" data-cycle-title=@Parameter.sliderHeading   
data-cycle-desc="Remember, you are not limited to image elements. You can display 
other HTML too." data-cycle-link="#"></div>

        }
}
```

}

So, in macro, parameter value is accessed by  :- data-cycle-
   title=@Parameter.sliderHeading.

Now my issue is that 
   if property value is :- "My First Slide". Then it will give wrong output "My" on page.
   if property value is :- "My First Slide" with html space (&nbbsp;) in between Then it 
   will  give right output    "My First Slide" on page.

How should I access parameter in Macro, so that it will give right output.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit simple but won't wrapping @Html.Raw or even @Raw round your code force the parameter to output with spaces?

Like:

```
data-cycle-title=@Raw(Parameter.sliderHeading)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its giving  "The name 'Raw' does not exist in the current context" error. Do I need to import any namespace for the same.